# Brightness Problem Gradually Changing At Every Restart

Tags: 12.10, laptop, brightness

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Whenever I restart my Laptop my system brightness is changing.What settings should I make so that brightness doesn't change on every restart

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model of your laptop?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run this command:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`.

   Save the file and quit the text editor.
3. Then run: `sudo update-grub`
4. Restart.

Comment: Ist It Worked For You?

Answer (score 0):

this link worked for me..i am using pavillion dv6 ubuntu 12.10

http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html#comment-form

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain and quote the necessary steps from the link? The linked source might be down someday.